# How do developers maintain front-end dependencies on non-app projects?

Tags: jquery, node.js, wordpress, git, npm

I understand NPM and I use it a lot on my front-end projects for build scripts etc, but I'm curious how people handle maintaining front-end dependencies for non-app based "brochure-site" projects?

So for example, lets say I have a WordPress theme I'm working on and I need to include jQuery and a few jQuery plugins for some basic front-end stuff (like maybe a carousel or modal feature). Would you use NPM for this?

These scripts would need to be committed with my repo and deployed along with the theme to production. But NPM's `node_modules` directory is ignored in most projects. So how would you accomplish this without just manually including the scripts directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bower.io](http://bower.io), it works the same way that NPM does and is specifically designed for front-end packages.

Instead of a package.json, it has a bower.json and just like in the package.json, it stores the installed dependencies. The dependencies are stored in a dependencies array when installed via `bower install --save`. Installed packages are stored in a directory by default named bower_components.

Comment: In a comment on their homepage, Bower.io says: "...psst! While Bower is maintained, we recommend yarn and webpack for new front-end projects!"

Does that mean they're ending production on that project? Also, is there a way to set where modules get saved?

Comment: Doesn't sound like it since they said they're going to continue maintaining the project. You can change the save location by adding a `.bowerrc` file in your project root and setting the `"directory"` property to whatever desired location in your project you want.

Comment: I wonder why they suggest using yarn or webpack instead then? I'm also curious how Bootstrap manages their assets for their docs. You can see in their `bootstrap/docs/assets/js/vendor/` directory they have a set of vendor scripts they use, but they probably just maintain that manually?

Either way, thanks!